# Avoid seperate file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to execute following command **which works well**

I am executing test.sh which inturns call script1.sh.

Successful run , output as below

```
applicationuser@servername:/application> sudo ./test.sh
damn, there was an error
timeout happened
```

contents of both files are as below

test.sh

```
timeout 10 script1.sh  && echo "timeout not happened" || echo "timeout happened"
```

script1.sh as below

```
if ech "right echo" 2>/dev/null ; then echo 'command was successful'; else echo 'damn, there was an error'; fi
```

But when I combine both scripts into a single file(test.sh) like below ,

test.sh

```
timeout 10 if ech "right echo" 2>/dev/null ; then echo 'command was successful'; else echo 'damn, there was an error'; fi  && echo "timeout not happened" || echo "timeout happened"
```

I will get syntax error like below when i execute the script

> applicationuser@servername:/application> sudo ./test.sh ./test.sh: line
> 1: syntax error near unexpected token `then' ./test.sh: line 1:` timeout 10 if ech "right echo" 2>/dev/null ; then echo 'command was
> successful'; else echo 'damn, there was an error'; fi  && echo
> "timeout not happened" || echo "timeout happened"'

How to eliminate script1.sh and put its contents in test.sh and execute without syntax errors?

Comment: `timeout` basically executes the external commans, which you supply, as a child process, **not** in a subshell. Since there is no executable file named `if`, it does not work. For the same reason, `alias foo=ls; timeout 10 foo` would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be running the command using directly bash:

```
timeout 10 bash -c 'if ech "right echo" 2>/dev/null ; then echo "command was successful"; else echo "damn, there was an error"; fi  && echo "timeout not happened" || echo "timeout happened"'
```

Comment: Thanks it working for eleminating script1.sh , there is slight change i made to make timeout work   
timeout 10 bash -c 'sleep 11; if ech "right echo" 2>/dev/null ; then echo "command was successful"; else echo "damn, there was an error"; fi'  && echo "timeout not happened" || echo "timeout happened" , thanks for the idea !